# What does 'category__in' mean in queries?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, categories

Can someone please help me understand what does the following statements mean?

Specifically `array($category->term_id)`?

```
'category__in' => array($category->term_id)
```

Does that mean this query would include array of all category id?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable **$category** is a single category (has to be set somewhere before), and the **$category->term_id** is the ID of that category.

And, **array($category->term_id)** is an array with one element only, and that element is category ID. **'category__in'** argument requires an array of categories, and if you have one category even, it has to be placed in the array.

So, this query will include all posts belonging to a single category, defined by the **$category** variable.

Comment: oh but we just passed only category id, how it would include all posts for that single category?

Comment: This will include posts for that one category, it is a single category specified by the ID. Is the $category defined prior to the query?

Comment: oh yeah it was defined prior to query. See below: 

     `$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
   foreach($categories as $category) {
     $args=array(
       'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
       'caller_get_posts'=>1,
       'posts_per_page' => -1
     );`

Comment: So, this foreach will go through each category and will create arguments for WP_Query where each time query will get all posts belonging to each category. Is this what you need?